# Two ints to one double C++

Tags: c++, double, int

I am having a bit of a problem here.
I have two `int` values, one for dollars and one for cents. My job is to combine them into one `double` value and I am having some trouble.
Here's an example of what I want to be able to do:

```
int dollars = 10
int cents = 50
<some code which I haven't figured out yet>
double total = 10.50
```

I want to think it is relatively simple, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just saying, playing with doubles and money is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by thinking how you would solve this as a simple arithmetic problem, with pencil and paper (nothing to do with C). Once you find a way to do it manually, I'm sure the way to program it will seem trivial.

Comment: Well, here's some more complication due to the default integer division if both operands are integers... the "obvious" `total=dollar+cents/100;` won't work correctly...

Comment: Thank you! I was just forgetting to divide `cents` by 100! Paper can be helpful sometimes!!

Comment: @sinelaw: sure, it was only that I thought that the "algorithm" was obvious, and that he was experiencing some C++-specific difficulty. It turns out that you were right.

Answer (score 0):

That's not difficult... you have to convert `dollars` to a `double`<sup>1</sup> and add `cents` multiplied for `0.01` (or divided by `100.` - notice the trailing dot, that's to indicate that `100.` is a `double` constant, so `/` will perform a floating-point division instead of an integer division).

... but be aware of the fact that storing monetary values in binary floating-point variables is not a good idea at all, because binary doesn't have a finite representation of many "exact" decimal amounts (e.g. 0.1), that will be stored in an approximate representation. Working with such values may yield "strange" results when you start to do some arithmetic with them.

---

1. Actually, depending on your expression, it's probably not necessary due to implicit casts.

Answer (score 0):

How about `double total = double(dollars) + double(cents) / 100.0;`?

Note that `double` is not a good data type to represent 10-based currencies, due to its inability to represent `1/100` precisely. Consider a fixed-point solution instead, or perhaps a decimal float (those are rare).

Comment: Er... homework tag, is it a good idea to provide the solution ready-made?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Whoops, too late ... though that said, if *this* poses a major obstacle to the OP, I doubt that knowing the solution would make a big difference in the Grand Scheme. I chose to take this as a question about float-to-integral conversion in C++, rather than as a question about division by 100...

Comment: It seems that the question was actually about division by 100... `:S`

Comment: Using double to represent fractions of cents is probably only a good idea if you're attempting an 'Office Space' style scam.

Comment: @Clinton: Did **you** take my stapler?! Anyway, you will always have to deal with rounding one way or another (consider computing interest), but indeed, this needs to be well specified, deterministic and auditable. I don't have experience myself, but I think banks do use decimal floats to that end, though personally I'd probably pick some fixed-point integer scheme (with suitable multiplication helper functions).

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in 'the whole idea' of programming and not only in getting your homework right, I suggest you think about this: "Is there any way I can represent a whole dollar as a certain amount of cents?" Why should you ask this? Because if you want to represent two different 'types' of certain values as one value, you need to 'normalize' them or 'standardize' them in a way so that there is not any data loss or corruption (or at least for the smaller problems).

Also I agree with Kerrek SB, representing money as `double` might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just as easy: total = dollars + (cents/100); ?

No reason to complicate this.